# How to show distance between two horizontal lines in a graph

Tags: plotting, graphics, legending, symbols

I want to plot a like this[image]

So far, I am able to plot it like this[image]

**

> **However, I am unable to add that `\[Sigma]` symbol between those two**
> **dashed lines.**

> How do I do that?

**

This is a part of my code

```
Plot[1/128*x^4 - 0.25*x^2 + 0.15*Sqrt[(1/128)/(2*0.25)]*x, {x, -6, 6},
  Epilog -> {Directive[AbsoluteThickness[1], Dashed, Magenta], 
   InfiniteLine[{0, -1.94}, {1, 0}], InfiniteLine[{0, -2.09}, {1, 0}]}]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This method uses `Show` to display the gap label on top of the `Plot`.  The gap label is created as a `Graphics` complex using a few parameters.

```
plot = Plot[1/128*x^4 - 0.25*x^2 + 0.15*Sqrt[(1/128)/(2*0.25)]*x,
   {x, -6, 6}, PlotRange -> {All, {-3, All}}];

gapLabel = 
  With[{x = -1, vlo = -2.09, vhi = -1.94, a = .5, text = "\[Sigma]"},
   Graphics[{Black, Arrow[{{x, vlo - a}, {x, vlo}}],
     Arrow[{{x, vhi + a}, {x, vhi}}],
     Text[Style[text, Black, 14], {x + a, (vhi + vlo + a)/2}],
     {Dashed, Magenta, InfiniteLine[{0, vlo}, {1, 0}],
      InfiniteLine[{0, vhi}, {1, 0}]}}]
   ];

Show[{plot, gapLabel}]
```

[image]

The parameters `vlo` and `vhi` are used to locate the dashed lines vertically.  The `x` parameter is used to locate the arrowheads horizontally.  The `a` parameter controls the length of the arrows and is used to locate the $\sigma$ label relative to midpoint of the arrowheads.

If more gaps must the labeled, `gapLabel` should be turned into a function to accommodate whatever parameters are required to achieve the desired results.

Answer (score 3):

One minimal way is `Epilog` which already appears in the code

Edited: added an [updown arrow](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpDownArrow.html) next to $\sigma$.

```
point = {0, -2}; text = "σ, ↕";
Plot[1/128*x^4 - 0.25*x^2 + 0.15*Sqrt[(1/128)/(2*0.25)]*x, {x, -6, 6},
  Epilog -> {Point[point], Text[text, point + {0.4, -0.01}], 
   Directive[AbsoluteThickness[1], Dashed, Magenta], 
   InfiniteLine[{0, -1.94}, {1, 0}], 
   InfiniteLine[{0, -2.09}, {1, 0}]}, ImageSize -> Full]
```

[image: p1]

Comment: Thank you. But is there any way to add a double-headed arrow mark between the dashed lines next to sigma?

Comment: @user84456 you mean pointing up and down like in the image in the OP?

Comment: yes, just like that.

Comment: @user84456 please see the updated response. the arrow is there